# Android SDK ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis

How can I `query` only certain columns from ArcGIS map service?

```
featureLayer = new ArcGISFeatureLayer("http://+"ip"+/arcgis/rest/services/saha/saha_3857/FeatureServer/0", MODE.ONDEMAND );
featureLayer1 = new ArcGISFeatureLayer("http://+"ip"+/arcgis/rest/services/saha/saha_3857/FeatureServer/1", MODE.ONDEMAND );

// build a query to select the clicked feature
Envelope envelope = new Envelope(pointClicked,tolerance, tolerance); 
Query query = new Query();
query.setOutFields(new String[]{"*"});
query.setSpatialRelationship(SpatialRelationship.INTERSECTS);
query.setGeometry(envelope);
query.setInSpatialReference(mapView.getSpatialReference())
```

Comment: StackOverflow works best when you ask one question at a time -- please pick one of your three issues! Also, do you have more code than just your `featureLayer` definitions, or not?

Comment: Ok. My feature layer has 18 columns but I want to select 5 columns. How can I do while I call feature layer?

Comment: A simple way would be publish the map service with only 5 attributes instead of all 18. If the service needs all 18, however, then why are you selecting only 5 -- simpler display, simpler querying?

Comment: I don't publish only 5  attributes. How can use query for 5  attributes? Can you give me example code? Thanks

Comment: Envelope envelope = new Envelope(pointClicked,tolerance, tolerance);

                // build a query to select the clicked feature
                Query query = new Query();
                query.setOutFields(new String[]{"*"});
                query.setSpatialRelationship(SpatialRelationship.INTERSECTS);
                query.setGeometry(envelope);

                query.setInSpatialReference(mapView.getSpatialReference());

Comment: Instead of adding relevant content as a comment, you should edit your answer to improve its quality. You should also decide which of your 3 questions you want answered.

Answer (score 3):

You should get only the fields you want replacing the `*` in the line below:

```java
query.setOutFields(new String[]{"*"});
```

As, for example:

```java
query.setOutFields(new String[]{"field1", "field2"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The place to specify only a certain number of fields in the query is this line:

```
query.setOutFields(new String[]{"*"});
```

From [the Esri documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/tasks/query/QueryParameters.html#setOutFields(java.lang.String%5B%5D)):

> ```
> public void setOutFields (String[] outFields)
> ```
>
> Sets the array of fields to be included in the returned result set. For the query results to include all the field values, specify the wildcard '*' character as the value of this parameter.

So right now, your code is requesting *all* fields. To limit that, pass a list of fields instead of `"*"`.